# django request.POST.getlist[my_list', None] returns [] for non-existant keys

Tags: django, list, request

I'm using Django 1.10.2.

In a view, the below return []

```
    print(request.POST.getlist('collected_already', None))
    print(request.POST.getlist('collected_already[]', None))
    print(request.POST.getlist('non_existent', None))
    print(request.POST.getlist('non_existent[]', None))
```

I would expect None to be returned for the non_existent keys, and [] returned when an empty list is sent.

My workaround is to send and detect ['blank'] instead of [].

I'd appreciate pointers. With best wishes, Andy.

Answer (score 6):

The [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) returns the empty list `[]` by default. If you pass `default=None`, then that is treated as 'no default specified', not as 'default to None`.

If you want to coerce the empty list `[]` to `None`, then you could simply add `or None` to the end of the expression.

```
print(request.POST.getlist('collected_already') or None)
```

This works because of the way Python evaluates [boolean expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist). If `x` and `y` both evaluate to False, then `x or y` returns `y`.

Answer (score 0):

I think getlist() takes default argument as None and returns empty list [ ] if key is not found.

[Check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

> Returns the data with the requested key, as a Python list. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and no default value was provided. It’s guaranteed to return a list of some sort unless the default value provided is not a list.

Comment: The docs you linked to show that `getlist` *does* take an optional default argument. The problem is that `default=None` is treated as 'no default specified'.